# want to select user from onchange of dropdown list of department in cakephp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i have two tables user and department where department has two fields id and name i want to create a view so that when someone selects a department name from the dropdownlist the user's name of all in that department show in another dropdownlist using AJAX and How to call that in controller

```
 <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    //jQuery('#searchTable').dataTable();
    $('#department_id').change(function () {
        jQuery('#user').empty();
        var data2 = {};
        data2['department_id'] = jQuery(this).val();
        var json = JSON.stringify(data2);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/AjaxRequests/name",
            data: json,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                var app = "<option value>All</option>";
                jQuery('#user').append(app);

                jQuery.each(response, function (i, text) {
                    jQuery('#user').append(jQuery('<option></option>').val(i).html(text));
                });

            }
        });
    });
   </script>
```

this is the script i am using 
and in view the department dropdown is like this

```
     <?php echo $this->Form->input('department_id', array('onChange' => 'showFields(this.value)', 'class' => 'form-control-custom', 'id' => 'department_id', 'type' => 'select', 'label' => true, 'label' => 'department:', 'options' => $departments, 'empty' => 'Select A Department', 'required' => 'false'))
    ?>
```

Anyone please help me with this ajax and also the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, can u try to replace `'id' => 'department'` with `'id' => 'department_id'` . Cause it's seen here you are using **department_id** as selector but your **department_id** id as not declared in dropdownlist. Here you declared **department** as ID. So selector is not found. So Just replace `'id' => 'department'` with ''id' => 'department_id'', Hope it can be helpful to you.

Comment: Here is the simple steps you can follow and implement it http://php-tutorial-guide.blogspot.in/2015/07/jquery-populate-city-country-dropdown.html